# Batch String Manipulation with %~n2%4

Tags: batch-file

Hi I have a file name stored in a variable  and i need to remove few words from it.
I have tried with %~n2%4.... But I am unable to get  desired results.
Below is the code that I am trying to execute:
File name is: ABDYZW.CAMERA25-02182015-041435751-245707205016.XYZ18169D11424232904351999S

so from above i need to remove XYZ18169D11424232904351999S and i am trying to achive this functionality with %~n2%4. I know there are several ways through which we can parse the string , but the drawback is except XYZ rest of the name is changing whenever a new file come.

```
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s "%Source%"') do (
echo %%f >>%FileList%
    )
    FOR /f %%a IN (%FileList%) DO (
    if not "%%~xa"==".txt" rename "%%~fa" "%%~nxa.txt"
)
REM Again it will repeat the above process that will get new names of the files

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s "%Source%"') do (
     echo %%f >>%FileList%
    )
    FOR /f %%a IN (%FileList%) DO (
    if not "%%~xa"==".txt" rename "%%~fa" "%%~nxa.txt"
)

   Set FileName=%~nx2%4
   IF "%FileName:XYZ=%" neq "%FileName%" (
GOTO REMOVEXYZ
) else GOTO WITHOUTXYZ

:REMOVEXYZL
Set NewFileName=%~n2%4.123456789-txt
GOTO PROCESSING

:WITHOUTXYZ
Set NewFileName=%~nx2%4.123456789-txt
GOTO PROCESSING
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seeing that you have posted 14 questions now and not accepted an answer on a single one of them, I strongly suggest you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: What do you think does `%~n2%4` mean?

Comment: You realized that %2 and %4 are arguments passed to the batch file at time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

not quite clear, what you want.

just removing `.XYZ*`?

```
for %%i in (*.xyz*) do echo ren "%%i" "%%~ni"
```

Replacing it with another extension?

```
for %%i in (*.xyz*) do echo ren "%%i" "%%~ni.AnotherExtension"
```

(remove `echo`, if the output satisfies you)

Comment: Actually i need to remove XYZ18169D11424232904351999S from the file name: ABDYZW.CAMERA25-02182015-041435751-245707205016.XYZ18169D11424232904351999S 
I want to achive this functionality with %~n2%4 and want to rename the file with new name %~n2%4.123456789-txt.
As job was doing the same task previously but after rename it stopped removing XYZ18169D11424232904351999S from the file name

Comment: `%~n2%4` means: "take a substring (anything before the last dot) from Parameter 2 and append Parameter 4. You don't have any Parameters....

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%x in ("%filename%") do echo %%x.%%y
```

Comment: sure, you don't need any `tokens`? Also note, the example file name has _two_ dots, which means, the number of dots may vary.

Comment: Oops, corrected... I understand that all file names will have 2 dots, if not - then I don't know what he wants.